# Creating Dynamic/Deep-Link URL from Submission Form

Tags: java, forms

I'm looking to create a hotel booking form that automatically generates a URL based on the information inputted into the form.

For example, if a person inputs the name of "John" and the date "12/23/1989" I need the form to generate a URL such as "fakeurl.com/n=JOHNd=12231989" and automatically direct to this link when the form is submitted.

Using a few tutorials (I don't know Java very well), I was able to piece this together:
http://codepen.io/JeremyMG/pen/ptaGE

However, I am unsure how to make the fields match up with the variables.

If anyone could give me a hand or post a working example, that would be great! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="GET" action="https://fakeurl.com">
    <input type="text" name="n" value="john" />
    <input type="date" name="d" value="12/23/1989" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Set the FORM tag's METHOD attribute to GET

Comment: Thanks LastCoder! Do I need to rename the VARs in order to match the forms NAMEs? I'm having a hard time figuring out how the JS knows which field belongs to which variable.

Comment: Ohh I see. It doesn't seem like I need to use JS at all. Correct?

Comment: @JeremyE - no JS is required. You could even open the submission in a new window/tab using the TARGET attribute in the FORM tag, with the value of "_blank" (target="_blank"). You could use JavaScript to display the link on the new page using the window.location.href if you wanted to.